# What's the type of blur in this?

Tags: after-effects, premiere-pro, bluray

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TYpc0I3lBJQ) video,

I'm curious about the type of blur used in the photo below.
[image]
[image]
[image]

I think it's not a Gaussian Blur(Because Gaussian Blur looks like this
[image]

or a Direction Blur(Because Direction Blur looks like this
[image]
), but it's not flat.

Comment: The third image looks a bit like a Radial Blur. The others could be a Camera Blur in After Effects

Answer (score 0):

Having watched the video, it looks a lot like the Red Giant Chromatic Abberation plugin:

https://www.maxon.net/en/red-giant/universe/chromatic-aberration

Comment: But that has no rgb split, that has only blur.